# Unit tests with GUID

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, guid

Is it possible to create GUIDS with a manually defined value?

I need to know the value of the GUID in advance to do some unit tests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var guid = new Guid("62FA647C-AD54-4BCC-A860-E5A2664B019D");
```

Assuming you are using .Net

If you look at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc.aspx) you will see a full list of all the different types of string representations of GUIDs that are possible.

Comment: Ok, thanks this works. I have tried it with different positions of the dashes. Are the dashes in .Net Guids always placed like this? Do different .Net Guid versions exist?

Comment: @Moo - Yes, if you look at the MSDN docs *(link above)* then you will see examples.

Answer (score 2):

stumbled across this 9 years later. For testing, I've written an extension method that allows fake (repeatable) Guid

```cs
public static Guid AsGuid(
        this string src)
    {
        // Use MD5 since (1) it's faster then SHA and (2) it's already 16 bytes which matches the Guid
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(src)
            ? Guid.Empty
            : new Guid(MD5.Create().ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(src)));
    }
```

Then use like this : `"something".AsGuid()` or `"".AsGuid == Guid.Empty`

You can use this in your tests like this:

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData("A", "B", false)
[InlineData("A", "A", true)
[InlineData("", "A", false)
public void GivenStringsAreEqual_WhenEqual_ThenReturnsTrue(
    string guidA,
    string guidB,
    bool shouldBeEqual)
{
    Assert.Equal(
        shouldBeEqual,
        guidA.AsGuid() == guidB.AsGuid()
    );
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's actually really clever and useful. Definitely beats having to maintain a list of GUIDs in tests.